# Calling functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Trying to call the `closeOpenNavDropdowns` function within my `toggleDropdownNavState` function, but nothing is running and I am not getting errors. I've checked the compiled code and it's there.

EDIT: trying to call the fn like `this.closeOpenNavDropdowns();` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: this.closeOpenNavDropdowns is not a function`

```
const aboutDropdownNav = {
    setup() {
        $('.nav__main__about-dropdown--js').click(this.toggleDropdownNavState);

        // Handlers for when user clicks outside the dropdown to close
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            if ($('body').hasClass('about-dropdown--open') && !$(event.target).parents('.about-us-dropdown').length) {
                $('body').removeClass('about-dropdown--open');
            }
        })
    },
    toggleDropdownNavState(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('about-dropdown--open');
        this.closeOpenNavDropdowns;
    },
    closeOpenNavDropdowns() {
        console.log('closeOpenNavDropdowns in aboutDropdown.js');            
        $('body').removeClass('solutions-dropdown--open'); //close solution dropdown if its open
    }
}

module.exports = aboutDropdownNav;
```

and the above code is called by this other file:

```
var aboutDropdownNav = require('./nav-about-dropdown');

module.exports = function() {
    // About Dropdown Nav
    aboutDropdownNav.setup();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toggleDropdownNavState` function is attached to an eventListener. Inside an event handler function, `this` is a reference to the event's current target. That's why `closeOpenNavDropdowns` is not a function in the object referenced by `this`.

There are many ways to solve that issue. One of them is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force the binding between the `closeOpenNavDropdowns` function and your object.

```js
const aboutDropdownNav = {

setup: function() {
    
    $('.nav__main__about-dropdown--js').click(this.toggleDropdownNavState.bind(this));

    // Handlers for when user clicks outside the dropdown to close
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('about-dropdown--open') && !$(event.target).parents('.about-us-dropdown').length) {
            $('body').removeClass('about-dropdown--open');
        }
    })
},
toggleDropdownNavState : function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').toggleClass('about-dropdown--open');
    this.closeOpenNavDropdowns();
},
closeOpenNavDropdowns : function() {
    console.log('closeOpenNavDropdowns in aboutDropdown.js');

    $('body').removeClass('solutions-dropdown--open'); //close solution dropdown if its open
}

}

aboutDropdownNav.setup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nav__main__about-dropdown--js" value="Click"/>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I even tried adding `.bind(this)` to my `this.closeOpenNavDropdowns()` call but didn't work. Thanks for the help this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The context, when calling `this.toggleDropdownNavState` is wrong, bind it to the proper context.

```
$('.nav__main__about-dropdown--js').click(this.toggleDropdownNavState.bind(this));
```

And you are missing the brackets `()` to call the function, you just referencing the function.

```
toggleDropdownNavState(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').toggleClass('about-dropdown--open');
    this.closeOpenNavDropdowns();
},
```

Comment: When i try it this way i get `Uncaught TypeError: this.closeOpenNavDropdowns is not a function`